# Fade in image until another image is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-animate

Currently I have every image set to opacity 0.5 but when I click on one image I want it to change to 1 and then go back to 0.5 when another image is clicked. I also have a hover function that changes opacity while hovering, will these two functions interfere with each other?

I currently have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, "slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'}, "slow");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabmenu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Pavan Suryaprakash</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nikhil Bansal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A D Dheeraj</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rohan Chawla</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Neelam Agarwal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipshita Ghoshdastidar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sumit Kumar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abhimanyu Sharma</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vivek Ranjan Gupta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shrish Mishra</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Priyadarshini</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rajesh Dass</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gaurav Prakash Pandey</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Diana Varghese</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sagar Dharwar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Saloni Chadha</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subhra Shaw</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sweety Gupta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trishendu Deb</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gunjan Tekriwal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rakesh Sahu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Karthik Sivaraman</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sumit Vats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subhash Agarwal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bina Rajput</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CLICK HANDLER

```
$("#nav li a").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, "slow");
    });
```

Comment: Post some `html` too

Comment: Show the click handler too.

Comment: @AlexBay I have added it now

Comment: There are anchor tag no image to show.

Comment: @ketan the image is loaded into the a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep it simple and use CSS animation with simple javascript instead?

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/wMeXvB

For your css:

```
a{
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
 transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

#nav li a{
  opacity:.5;
}

#nav li a.currentClick{
  opacity:1;
}

#nav li a:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

For your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#nav li a").click(function() {
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("currentClick");
      $(this).addClass("currentClick");
  });

});
```

If you are working with images just replace the `<a>` element with your images since CSS opacity will work well with images as well.

Comment: And css is so mutch faster the javascript! Nice example!

Comment: @Zorken17 that's what css3 is for ;-)

Comment: @Vincent1989 thanks this way seems a lot more simple, I have now tried it but when I click it changes back to 0.5 once I take the mouse off the image

Comment: Sorted it, was being overridden, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).stop().animate(...)` if you need the new animation to override the running one. This will avoid the old animation to perform until end and immediately starts the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, "slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '0.5'}, "slow");
    });
});
```